# What is the best way to resolve a tree conflict with TortoiseSVN if I want to keep my local changes?

Tags: svn, tree, tortoisesvn, conflict, directory

I've been unfortunate enough to run into a lot of tree conflicts with myself lately on this project I'm working on. I want to know what is the best and simplest way to resolve a tree conflict if I want to keep my local changes only. Thank you.

Comment: simple just push your code into tortoise-svn and update your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on file > Edit Conflicts > Mark as Resolved.